# Angular issue with window style

Tags: angular, ngrx

I take the liberty of posting a message because I've been stuck for a few days on a problem in angular,

I develop a website with a window system like for an operating system, it turns out that I have some difficulty, I use the ComponentFactoryResolver to generate my different components in my page.

It turns out that when two windows coming from the same component are open and I write in the first one it passes normally, the writing is displayed in the desired window but not in the other one but when I change window, I receive the data of the other window in this one.

Anyone have any ideas?

I use ngrx to manage the states in my app.

Comment: are you using an input the an id? if so they are going to have the same id in both windows.

Comment: I use unique id for any window, the issue come when after typing a value in the first window then I enter another value in the other one which is open
I'm using the HostListener to catch the keyboard event.
I give you an example: I enter "Hello world" in the first window, when I go to the second window, there is no value displayed, once I start entering a value (d) for example this one displays "Hello Worldd".

Comment: without seeing the code its going to be hard to debug. not even sure what you mean by "window".

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsmDx.gif

Comment: even if you are using a unique id for each window, if the input field id is not unique, you could get this behavior.

Comment: I have solve the problem, I dispatch application id in subscribe (bad idea) it's the origin of that, it's working now

Comment: Might you share the code you have?